# Creating graph.data.frame to generate genealogic tree

Tags: r, igraph, genealogy

Hello I would create genealogic tree from my data using ggenealogy. I am stacked on the begging, when I try to create igraph. My data (small part).

`df<-data.frame(child=c("82Y-02938", "82Y-02939","82Y-02938", "82Y-02939"), parent=c("81Y-02080", "81Y-02439", "81Y-02080", "81Y-02439"))`

`ig<-dfToIG(dff)`

and I get the error **Error in igraph::graph.data.frame(d = edges, directed = isDirected, vertices = nodes) : 
  Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame**

I have no idea, what is wrong.  Thanks for a help

**Problem Solved**

It is necessery to have also parents in child (=vertex) column and for them to have NA as parents.

`df<-data.frame(child=c("82Y-02938", "82Y-02939","82Y-02938", "82Y-02939","81Y-02080", "81Y-02439"), parent=c("81Y-02080", "81Y-02439", "81Y-02080", "81Y-02439",NA,NA))`

Comment: igraph does not have a function called `dfToIG`. where did you get that function?  Or did you mean `graph_from_data_frame`?

Comment: `g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)`.

Comment: I used function dfToIG becouse it is part of package ggeenealogy and use directly function graph.data.frame